# Quadratic extension of an irrational number

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $\alpha\in\mathbb R_{>2}\setminus\mathbb Q$ be an irrational number and let $\beta$ be such that
$$\alpha+\beta+\frac{1}{\beta}=0.$$
Is there a known relationship between the irrationality measure of $\beta$ and that of $\alpha$?

A maybe easier question: assume $\alpha$ is a Bruno number (very well approximated by rationals, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brjuno_number); then is $\beta$ Bruno? It more or less boils down to knowing whether the set $B$ of Bruno numbers is stable by taking quadratic extensions.

Comment: You can solve $\beta=\frac{1}{2}(\pm\sqrt{a^2-4}-a)$ ([WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+x%2B1%2Fx%2Ba%3D0)). The question therefore seems to essentially come down to questions about relating irrationality measure of a number and its square root.

Comment: Yes, that's basically what I meant in the question.